# How to make elements not editable in visual editor

Tags: visual-editor

I have bootstrap grid in some pages, which I've made visibale in the editor by styling in editor styles.

Is there a way to make the column div not removable in visual editor, kind of like how you can't delete a table cell with a backspace. So that when a client deletes the text in a div and keeps pressing the backspace it wont delete the div itself? However I do want the code to be editable when you switch to Text tab.

Also is there a way to make an entire div read only so that it could not be edited in the visual tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is doable on the default visual editor. You can try one of the plugin solutions out there. The most popular ones are:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/beaver-builder-lite-version/ (freemium)
- Visual Composer (careful seem there's an issue with 4.5)
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/screenshots/ (just make easier to add HTML elements)

One other approach to solve the problem is for you to create your own custom template. Then, you can have custom fields populating the content on the template: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
You will need PHP and WordPress developer skills to accomplish that. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason I'm trying to do that, is that the client is trying to avoid using visual editor plugins. There are multiple rows and columns on home page, so making a custom field for each column in each row seem excessive. I was just hoping to make the page more break-proof.